# WPF Control Hosted in WinForm Blocks WinForm controls from loaded even with thread

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have WPF Control hosted in winform which have Menu and some labels.
the WPF controls connect to internet to download some data.
I divide the code into two steps
first just set the control properties
second connect to net
the second runs inside thread, 
but Winform controls doesn't take place on the form until the WPF control finish his two steps.

I have tried many approach to make it thread-able
but all ways goes to same destination.

CODE
1- Load WPF Control

```
private void MDI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MenuManager.FillMenu(MainMenu); // I have filled WinForm Menu first, but it doesn't appear until WPF finish

        #region = WPF Control =

        wpfManager.AddweatherControl();
        wpfManager.weatherManager.Start(); // This have to run in another thread

        #endregion
}
```

2- wpfManager.weatherManager.Start

```
    public void Start()
{
    //var tsk = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(GetWeather);
    //tsk.ContinueWith(t => { MessageBox.Show(t.Exception.InnerException.Message); },
    //   System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
    //   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    //System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(
    //    () => weatherControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(GetWeather))
    //    );
    //t.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
    //t.Start();

    weatherControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(GetWeather), new object[] { });
}

void GetWeather()
{
    #region = Weather =
    Yweather.Getweather(UserManager.CurrentUser.Preferences.WeatherCity);

    if (Yweather.Online && Yweather.IDayForecast.Count > 0)
    {
        weatherControl.CurrentDegree.Text = Yweather.IDayForecast[0].CurrentTemperature.ToString();
        weatherControl.WeatherTypeName.Text = Yweather.IDayForecast[1].WeatherText;
        weatherControl.AllDayDegree.Text = Yweather.IDayForecast[1].LowTemperature + " - " + Yweather.IDayForecast[1].HighTemperature;
        weatherControl.WeatherType.Source = wpfManager.BitmapToImageSource(Yweather.IDayForecast[0].Image);

        xWeatherDay weatherday1 = weatherControl.OhterDaysPanel.Children[0] as xWeatherDay;
        weatherday1.AllDayDegree.Text = Yweather.IDayForecast[2].LowTemperature + " - " + Yweather.IDayForecast[2].HighTemperature;
        weatherday1.WeatherType.Source = wpfManager.BitmapToImageSource(Yweather.IDayForecast[2].Image);
    }
    else
    {
        weatherControl.CurrentDegree.Text = "0";
        weatherControl.WeatherTypeName.Text = "NAN";
        weatherControl.AllDayDegree.Text = "0 - 0";
        weatherControl.WeatherType.Source = wpfManager.BitmapToImageSource(Yweather.OfflineImage);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like from the code you posted that the delay is due to running `GetWeather` on the UI thread. Assuming that `weatherControl` is an instance of the WPF control, this runs on the UI thread because that is the thread that its dispatcher belongs to.

If you want to run code on a background thread, one easy way to do so is to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). You could use it something like this:

```
public void Start()
{
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
    {
        GetWeather();
        // put the results of getting the weather in to args.Result
    };
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
    {
        // use args.Result to update the UI
    };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

The code in the `DoWork` event handler runs on a background thread, while the code in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler runs on the UI thread.